# how to migrate doubles and dates from System.Data.OracleClient to ODP.NET?

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odp.net, system.data.oracleclient

This migration seem to be really challenging. What i'm trying to do now is to execute simple queries to a oracle db table:

```
OBJECTID NOT NULL NUMBER,
DOUBLEVALUE NOT NULL FLOAT(126),
MODTIME DATE
```

when I use System.Data.OracleClient I can INSERT parametrized queries where parameter values are:

```
123, 
"123.123", 
DateTime.Now.ToString().
```

and DbParameter.DbTypes are:

```
DbType.Int32,
DbType.Double,
DbType.Date
```

If I use Oracle.DataAccess.Client this is not working:

For DOUBLEVALUE I get exception because in my system Convert.ToDouble (which is called by OracleParameter.PreBind_Double) expects that I use comma ("123,123"). I do not want to change all the values in all programs and files. Also OleDb can handle this without problems.

For MODTIME I get "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string." This works if I change the value to DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(). Possibly also if I change the parameter type. Also this OleDb can handle.

It seems ridiculous that Oracle.DataAccess.Client cannot handle these really basic situations which System.Data.OracleClient and System.Data.OleDb have no problems. Any recommendations?

Thanks & Best regards -Matti

Comment: Why pass the DateTime as a string?  Just pass the DateTime directly!

Comment: thanks chris. I think 1 reason was that I used a method to  handle all kinds of values for all providers. of course that was not a good reason cause i could have used object instead of string as parameter for my own method. this worked for both OleDb and System.Data.OracleClient so I didn't give it much thought. one reason is also that I use the same method for values that I read from a text file. sooo what I gotta do is to make conversions 1st.

Comment: ok. this was completely my bad. i still have 1 (so far) issue concerning migration that is not related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095082/why-i-get-oracletruncateexception-with-odp-net-oracledataadapter-but-not-with-sy if you can help me with this one I'd be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with the comma comes from the default culture used by your processing thread. Try forcing en-US culture:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: thanks! that I kinda knew and that I'll do if there is nothing else I can do to configure the provier factory/connection/command to not act stupid. but I have a feeling that I've only scratch surface with all the problems related to Oracle.DataAccess.Client. according lots of opinions the whole Oracle.DataAccess.Client seems to suck.

Comment: both clients suck. they only headache is that they suck in different ways so they are not easily interchangeable :(.

Comment: also i don't quite understand why you are passing datetime values as strings and not directly the DateTime structure.

Comment: thanks AZ. read my comment from my question. anyway hope it works. cannot test it right now.